# White flashes appears when switching between indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, slider

I'm experiencing an issue in my React application where, upon clicking to show the next image in a slider, there is a noticeable white flash before the next image is displayed. I have a slider component (WorkData) that renders images based on an index (imageIndex) from an array (graphicDesignDataSlider).

Here is the code of Work.js:

```
 const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  function showNextImage() {
    setImageIndex((index) => {
      if (index === graphicDesignDataSlider.length - 1) return 0;
      return index + 1;
    });
  }

  function showPrevImage() {
    setImageIndex((index) => {
      if (index === 0) return graphicDesignDataSlider.length - 1;
      return index - 1;
    });
  }

 <div className="InfoData">
            <svg
              onClick={showNextImage}
            >
            </svg>
            {/* up arrow */}

            <svg
              onClick={showPrevImage}
            >
            </svg>
            {/* down arrow */}

            <div className="InfoDataSlider">
              {graphicDesignDataSlider.map((el, index) =>
                index === imageIndex ? <WorkData key={index} data={el} /> : null
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is the code of WorkData.js:

```
const WorkData = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`thumbNail ${props.data.className}`}>
      <a href={props.data.href} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={props.data.src} alt={props.data.alt} />
        <div className="thumbNailContent">
          <h2>{props.data.h2}</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorkData;
```

and if I may ask, how can I add a transform traslateY effect onclicking on 1 of the buttons with a transitions?